# no block given error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html says that I can use find_each to limit the number of rows returned by ActiveRecord. It also says that I do not have to specify a start and that the default order is ASC. In this case, I would not really be able to specify a start, as the index is a twitter ID.

This is what I have in my controller, in the index method:

```
@user = User.find_each(:batch_size => 100)
```

But when Rails tries to render the view, I get the following message:

```
no block given (yield)
```

Which tells me that Rails wants me to provide a block (as in a starting point and and end point).

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're just trying to limit a result set, read this section: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset

Comment: User.limit(xxx) will work, but that wasn't my question

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? `find_each` expects you to provide a block that will be executed for every user it finds.  What are you trying to store in `@user`?

Comment: That's a typo. It should be \\@users. @users = User.all stores all users. I want to store in \\@users 100 users. Reading the documentation, I thought that \\@users = user.find_each("batch_size => 100) will store the block in \\@users and the controller passes that to the Index view (the controller index method)

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each)

> Yields each record that was found by the find options. The find is performed by find_in_batches with a batch size of 1000 (or as specified by the :batch_size option).

I think you want to use `find_in_batches` directly. `find_each` is like a mooshed together `find_in_batches` and `each`. `each` expects a block. `find_each` says, "Find instances in blocks matching these criteria and then call the block I'm passing on each one."

Also, `@user` implies you're looking for one user but fetching multiples in batches. Is that what you want? If so, you probably want a simple `find`. If you want multiples, try `@users = User.find_in_batches` and then `@users.each do |user| ... end` in your view.

Comment: \@user was a typo. It should be \@users, as I'm trying to grab a block of users. I will try this and let you know if it works

Comment: I got the same error message when I did: @users = User.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100)

Comment: Are you trying to do batch processing or paging? Re-looking at the docs, batching would be great for something like a rake task to batch process through users, but if you're trying to just get a few users first, and then more on another page, you should use `find` with `:limit` and `:offset`

Comment: I'm trying to page through a very large DB. I'm trying to do it now through find with limit and offset.